# Signup form for admin in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

I have a parent table and in it there is a boolean field admin. I have a admin signup page where i want a hidden field for admin to set as true. Please help. I have tried the step below. please correct it as it is not working.

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class= 'col-xs-12'>
      <%= form_for(@parent, :html => { multipart: true, class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f| %>
        <div class = "form-group">
          <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
            <%= f.label :email, class: "required" %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter email", required: true %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group">
          <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
            <%= f.label :password, class: "required" %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter password", required: true %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "form-group">
          <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation, class: "required" %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Re-enter password", required: true %>
          </div>  
        </div>
        <%= f.hidden_field :admin, :value => true %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <%= f.submit 'Sign up', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Parent controller

```
    def addusers
        @parent=Parent.new
    end
```

Updated parent controller

```
    def new
        @parent = Parent.new
        @parent.secondaryparents.build
        add_breadcrumb "Home", :root_path
        add_breadcrumb "Sign up"
    end

    def addusers
        @parent=Parent.new
    end

    def create_users
        @parent=Parent.new(parent_params)
        @parent.admin = true
        if @parent.save
            ParentMailer.registration_confirmation(@parent).deliver
            flash[:success] = "Please ask user to confirm email address to continue"
            redirect_to main_admin_path
        else
            flash[:danger] = "There was an error with registering. Try again"
            redirect_to main_admin_path
        end
    end

def create
        @parent = Parent.new(parent_params)
        if @parent.save
            ParentMailer.registration_confirmation(@parent).deliver
            flash[:success] = "Please confirm your email address to continue"
            redirect_to root_path(@parent)
        else
            flash[:danger] = "There was an error with registering. Try again"
            redirect_to signup_path
        end
    end
```

Routes

```
resources :parents do
    resources :children do
        resources :fundings
        end
    end
end

get 'signup', to:'parents#new'
get 'login', to: 'sessions#new'
get 'usersignup', to:'parents#addusers'
post 'usersignup', to:'parents#create_users'

resources :parents, except: [:new] do
    member do
        get :confirm_email
    end
end
```

Comment: post controller also

Comment: @7urkm3n added. addusers.html.erb is the above signup form for admins

Comment: i think you need to add routes also

Comment: @7urkm3n i have already done that. **get 'usersignup', to:'parents#addusers'**.  All I want to do is set the parent as admin during signup with a hidden field which sets admin boolean field to true .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove hidden line from html page, no need it `f.hidden_field :admin, :value => true`

**Form_for**

```
form_for(@parent, url: usersignup_path, 
        :html => { multipart: true, class: "form-horizontal", role: "form"}) do |f|
```

**Add to routes:**

```
post 'usersignup', to:'parents#create_users'
```

**Controller:**

```
def create_users
   @parent = Parent.new(parent_params)
   @parent.admin = true
   if @parent.save
      #do yr logic here
   else
      redirect_back(fallback_location: "/", flash: { danger: "smth went wrong.." })
   end
end

def parent_params
    params.require(:parent).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Comment: Please check the updated parent controller above. it is still not working.

Comment: when i click on signup it run def create function rather than def create_users function. please check the updated parent controller above

Comment: do u have before_action methods ?, can u post properly routes ?

Comment: if it goes via `create` method just add this line `@parent.admin = true`

Comment: Please check the routes above. I can't add @parent.admin = true in create method because that method is used to create parents who are not admin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173844/discussion-between-7urkm3n-and-navroop-singh-sidhu).